# Dynamically created keydown event does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, eventhandler

I'm trying to make some often-used code more userfriendly.

I have a system that I use frequently in WinForms where the user needs to double-click a label to be able to edit the label.

Before, I always created the textbox and manually linked the KeyDown Event to the KeyDown EventHandler. But I wanted to make this easier by adding the eventhandler in the code.

However, when I do it this way, the KeyDown event isn't triggered.

Below This is the code to trigger the function that adds the KeyDown event to the TextBox

```
private void lbl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // LINK THE LABEL
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    
    // SET THE LABEL AS THE SELECTEDLABEL
    selectedLabel = lbl;
    
    // OPEN THE EDIT TEXTBOX
     editText();
}

private void editText()
{
    // SETUP THE PARAMETERS OF THE EDIT TEXTBOX
    txtEdit.Parent = this;
    txtEdit.KeyDown -= txtEdit_KeyDown;
    txtEdit.KeyDown += txtEdit_KeyDown;  
            
    // SOME OTHER CODE IS OMITTED FOR CLARITY                      
}
```

The above code links the KeyDown to the Event Handler.
At some point I found that I needed to relink the Event Handler every time, however, I'm not sure anymore why that was. I can't find the original post anymore.

Below is the Event Handler:

```
private void txtEdit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Escape:
    
            // HIDE THE EDIT TEXTBOX
            txtEdit.Visible = false;
    
            // CLEAR THE SELECTED LABEL
            selectedLabel = null;
            break;
    
        case Keys.Enter:
            break;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the Textbox gets created and the contents of the label are copied in the textbox. However when I hit any button inside of the
`txtEdit` textbox, the Key Down Event Handler is not being fired.

I have checked that in the Designer there is no Event Handler specified which might interfere with my new one:

```
// 
// txtEdit
// 
this.txtEdit.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.txtEdit.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.txtEdit.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.txtEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1607, 225);
this.txtEdit.Multiline = true;
this.txtEdit.Name = "txtEdit";
this.txtEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 35);
this.txtEdit.TabIndex = 22;
this.txtEdit.Text = "Edit";
this.txtEdit.Visible = false;
```

So I have no idea why this isn't working.
Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `editText()` method is being called?

Comment: What is the purpose of `EditTest()`? I find both the setting of `.parent` and detaching/reattaching event handlers suspect, I would not expect it to be needed.

Comment: Why are you setting the Parent? Why are you removing / resetting the event handler? It looks like you just want to make the TextBox visible (since it's not visible, as set in the Designer). Add the handler just once. Unless you have omitted something else relevant here. Is the TextBox disposed as some point? Something else?

Comment: The EditText() basically links the Label which was clicked, gets the text of that label and puts it into the Textbox. It then gets positioned on the same position as the label and is made visible. I'm referencing the form since I need to be able to position it everywhere on the form and not just related to the panel where the default position of the textbox is.

Comment: But you're hard-coding this as Parent, not the Label's Parent. It's not clear where that TextBox is meant to show up, or why it is child of a Panel, when you reset the Parent to a fixed reference when used. It's also not clear when this TextBox becomes visible. The event handler doesn't change at all anyway, unsubscribing / subscribing is not needed. You can add the handler in the Designer directly (since the TextBox is also added through the Designer). -- Is some other *sensible information* still missing?

Comment: Works for me, I did `txtEdit.Parent = selectedLabel.Parent` instead of `this`